# Modified (filtered) UIImage doesn't save in document directory

Tags: ios, image, file, filter

When I save an image taken with the camera without filtering it goes smoothly, but if i filter the image, when I save it, it doesn't work.

i'm using : `[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"]` and its options to filter.

Here the code used to save the image (wether or not its been filtered).

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
         NSData *binaryImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_photo, 0.3);  // PNG without compression paramenter works too
         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"];
         NSString *imageName = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
         [binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] atomically:YES];


}
```

**EDIT :** 
When I use the breakpoint, the NSData receives (counter) data and becomes nil when I proceed to NSDateFormatter

Comment: I have similar issue, i'll let you know if I find something !

Comment: if you use "`writeToFile:options:error:`" instead of "`writeToFile:atomically:`", you have an error parameter returned. Try using that. And then let me know What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: i'll do it but i forgot to say that my NSData become nil when i pass to the NSDateFormatter and it's fine when a use the "normal" image.

Comment: With "writeToFile:options:error:" , when i log the error, i got "null"